# Getting current month from array of months

Tags: jquery, arrays, date, swiper.js

I have an array which basically look like this:

This array is dynamic and lets say it has following months inside:

> "May","June"

It can be like this as well:

> "May","June","July"...

I need to be able to setup in my slider on the current month. I've been doing this like following:

```
swiper.slideTo(new DateTime().getMonth()); // fetches current month index ( if May it is 5 since indexation goes from 0)
```

And my slides looked like this:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>January</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>February</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>March</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>April</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>May</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>June</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>July</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>August</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>September</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>October</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>November</h3></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide active"><h3>December</h3></div>
</div>
```

And the indexation in the swiper were going from 0 to 11 as well so it was easy to set the current slide to the current month. The problem now is how can I set the current month if the array doesn't starts from January, but that I'm still able to set the current slide to the correct month... Like for example if slides start from May to July... If the current month is June, I'd like to be able to set the current slide to June...

How could I do this?

Comment: So you just want to select the correct swiper based on a search query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be really easy using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
var search = "May";

var indexOfCurrentMonthSwiper;

var currentMonthSwiper = $(".swiper-slide").filter(function(i){
    if ($(this).find("h3").html() == search){
      indexOfCurrentMonthSwiper = i;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(currentMonthSwiper, indexOfCurrentMonthSwiper);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/developius/4jddzp4m/)

Comment: I need to set the current month (from real life) so it matches with the slider index number.... Is this it ?

Comment: `indexOfCurrentMonthSwiper` will contain the index of the slide

Comment: Okay one sec I will try the solution and report back if it works :)

Comment: Hey @developius... So whatever I set into the "Search" Variable will be set as current month ?? :)

Comment: Wohoo it works , thanks a lot mate ! :) Accepted the answer and you sir rock!!! :) :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Javascript has a function out of the box to translate a month index to a string. But if not, the easiest would be to keep a fixed array containing all the months names in a variable and finding the index of the current month, which yields the name of the current month. You can then use that with an `.indexOf` on your slides array to get the index to set your slider to.

Could be something like this:

```
var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function getSliderIndex(slides) {
    var currentMonthName = MONTHS[new Date().getMonth()];
    return slides.indexOf(currentMonthName)
}
```

Comment: Hey @Bram I need to get current month name from JS and then set it in the slider...

Comment: @perkes456 Using that array with this should to the trick nicely: `return MONTHS[new Date().getMonth()];´

Answer (score 0):

If you were to give each div something to identify the month (this could be a CSS class, an ID, a data attribute, ...) you could iterate over the DIVS and pick the one you want.

Below an example with a custom data attribute:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
   <div class="swiper-slide active" data-month="0"><h3>January</h3></div>
   <div class="swiper-slide active" data-month="1"><h3>February</h3></div>
   ...
   <div class="swiper-slide active" data-month="11"><h3>December</h3></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var curr_month = new DateTime().getMonth();
$('.swiper-wrapper').children('div').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).data("month") === curr_month){
        swiper.slideTo(i);
    }
});
```